# Transfer parameters from training to inference graph

Tags: variables, tensorflow, inference

To not to carry optimizer and gradient nodes into inference environment, I'm trying to create two versions of graph - one with training nodes and the other one without.

And idea was to use `tensorflow.train.Saver` to pass variables from train graph version into inference graph version.

So I've tried the following:

```py
# Create training graph
trainingGraph = tf.Graph()
with (trainingGraph.as_default()):
  trainOp, lossOp = self.CreateTrainingGraph()
  trainInitOp = tf.initialize_variables(tf.all_variables(), "init_variables")

  # Add saver op
  self.saverOp = tf.train.Saver()

# Create inference graph
inferenceGraph = tf.Graph()
with (inferenceGraph.as_default()):
  self.CreateInferenceGraph()

  # Add saver op, compatible with training saver
  tf.train.Saver(saver_def=self.saverOp.as_saver_def())
```

In this case `CreateTrainingGraph()` calls `CreateInferenceGraph()` and adds optimizer and loss on top of it.

For some reason, `tf.train.Saver` constructor doesn't add `save/restore_all` node into the inference graph (or I just don't understand what `saver_def` option does). I've tried empty constructor and

```py
sess.run([model.saverOp._restore_op_name],
         { model.saverOp._filename_tensor_name : "Params/data.pb" })
```

failed with error

```py
<built-in function delete_Status> returned a result with an error set
```

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you construct your inference graph, you should be able to construct a [`tf.train.Saver()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver.__init__) with no arguments, and it will construct the appropriate save and restore ops for you. You should then be able to call [`saver.restore(sess, filename)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver.restore) to restore the variables from a file.

**N.B.** For the constructor to work with no arguments, (i) the variables in the inference graph (i.e. the result of [`tf.all_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#all_variables)) must be a subset of the variables in the training graph, and (ii) the corresponding variables must have exactly the same names. If either of these conditions doesn't hold, you will need to specify a variable name map to the saver constructor. (However, if `self.CreateTrainingGraph()` calls `self.CreateInferenceGraph()` before creating any other variables, and doesn't do anything different with [`tf.name_scope()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#name_scope), then this should be fine.)

(The `saver_def` argument is infrequently  used when you load in a graph—for example using [`tf.import_graph_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#import_graph_def)—that already contains the save and restore ops from a previously created Saver. It will then create a Saver in your Python program that reuses those ops, and you will get a mysterious error if the graph does not contain those ops.)

Comment: I'll try to update to latest version and find out why empty constructor didn't work for me. Probably some kind of bug or something stupid from my side.